# Установить в Visual Studio Community тему "Cyberpunk"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я нашел тему "Cyberpunk" для Visual Studio и захотел поставить ее себе. Как мне это сделать? Инструкции по установке я не нашел

[image: Тема Cyberpunk]

Comment: Большая жирная кнопка "Скачать", жмете, устанавливает, готово. Попутно читаете страницу, смотря для какой студии, что и как включать, и так далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions - Manage Extensions

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/836730)

Comment: с чего вы вообще взяли что это дополнение к вопросу? Вы разберитесь с начала, потом умничайте. Это ответ я написал.

Answer (score 0):

Можно найти необходимую тему внутри Visual Studio и уже там установить:

[image]

[Страница из документации на английском](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_color-themes-from-the-marketplace).

Comment: Я использую Visual Studio, не Visual Studio Code

Comment: Extensions - Manage Extensions